# handlebar.js is not rendering Spanish text e.g. aria-label="Hola Mundo"

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

There is a situation where I have to develop a page in two languages, English and Spanish and I am using handlebar.js for rendering the content on the browser.

In my markup, I am using some aria attributes as well. 
The `aria-label="Hello world"` is rendered perfectly fine in the browser (when I inspect, I can see this aria-label with the correct value), however, In Spanish, despite of giving `aria-label="Hola Mundo"`,in the browser, it is rendered as `aria-label="Hello world"` only.

Am I doing something wrong here? Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Here is my markup:
Spanish:

```
<div id=“abc” tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Hola Mundo" aria-describedby=“abcd-{{@index}}"></div>
```

English:

Thanks.

Comment: handlebar code: <div id=“abc” tabindex="0" role="button"  aria-label="Hola Mundo" aria-describedby=“abcd-{{@index}}"></div>

Comment: Either this is not the only code that you have with handlebar (there is a language condition missing) either you still execute the server code that is supposed to display the english language. You'll have to provide more informations.